# Reference to another field with in a func in the same struct in golang

Tags: struct, go

I have a struct looks something like this:

```
type Job struct {
    Action  func()
    Cron    string
}
```

So for an instance of this struct, is it possible for the code inside the implementation of `Action` to get a reference to `Cron`? Thanks.

Comment: No, Go has no notion of "reference". But Action may access Cron without any problems.

Comment: How can Action access Cron? I have some test code here: http://play.golang.org/p/5OGhIZR0Sx, but it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a closure to create the `Action` function:

```
func MakeAction(job *Job) func() {
    return func() {
        // function that uses the variable job
    }
}
```

You can use the `MakeAction` function like this:

```
j := &Job{ nil, "foo" }
j.Action = MakeAction(j)
```

Notice that this will behave in possibly unexpected ways when somebody makes a copy of the `Job` structure—the reference inside the closure created by `MakeAction()` will still point to the original instance (instead of the copy).

Comment: A separate initialization of Action, once Job is instantiated, would work indeed. +1. This seems closer to what the OP wants than in my answer.

Comment: What is the purpose of having a MakeAction function? Doesn't this do the same? "j.Action = func (){.../*reference j.Cron*/...}". I had the same problem as the OP and came up with this (working - but not really satisfied with it). I wonder if there is a better way...

Comment: @Wolf You can of course implement `MakeAction()` in line instead of making a separate function, but having a separate function is clearer and easier to explain in an answer. Plus you avoid any complications wrt. closing over local variables (such as, overwriting the variable with something else).

Comment: @fuz: Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to *have to* pass a `Job` reference to the `Action` function in order for said function to access `Cron`.

[See for instance](http://play.golang.org/p/mHEIM4QCJs):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Job struct {
    Action func(*Job)
    Cron   string
}

func main() {
    j := &Job{f, "test"}
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground", j)
    j.Action(j)
}

func f(j *Job) {
    fmt.Println(j.Cron)
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, playground &{0x201a0 test}
test
```

None of the [closures examples](https://gobyexample.com/closures) allows you to reference your own struct.

---

The OP adds:

> The external framework expects a function like this: `func()`.
>   I'm wrapping this function into my homebrewed struct `Job`, and I put something else into the `Job` struct.
>   Now I hope the `Action` could access other fields in `Job`, but it doesn't seem to be possible.
>   Later I will pass the `Action` directly into the external framework.

I confirm that, just by wrapping `func()` (from external framework) in a struct of yours doesn't means `f` has access to the struct fields through closure.
You need a separate initialization, as [FUZxxl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417501/fuzxxl)'s [answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27646651/6309).

Otherwise, how that function (from an external framework) would even know about `Job`?
That could only work if that function expect an interface with a `Cron()` function, not a struct which it knows nothing about, with a `Cron` field.
As in [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/elV65LIiKl).

Comment: Thanks @VonC. The thing is I have no control over the signature of `Action`, because it dictated by another framework. It accepts only no argument no return value function. If this is the case, is that to say it's not possible for code in Action to access Cron?

Comment: @ElgsQianChen how that function (from an external framework) would even know about `Job` then? That could only work if that function expect an interface with a `Cron()` function, not a struct which it knows nothing about, with a `Cron` field.

Comment: The external framework expects a function like this: `func()`. I'm wrapping this function into my homebrewed struct `Job`, and I put something else into the `Job` struct. Now I hope the `Action` could access other fields in Job, but it doesn't seem to be possible. Later I will pass the `Action` directly into the external framework.

Comment: I confirm that, just by wrapping `func()` (from external framework) in a `struct` of yours doesn't means `f` has access to your `struct` fields through closure.

Comment: thanks for the playground code. I think that the right direction solving my problem.